# Subscription to Observable.forkJoin is never called

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need to wait for the result of 2 AJAX requests to make some calculation on it.

I have found the `Observable.forkJoin` method that seems to do the job. So in my component I've added :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

// ...

ngOnInit() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.instrumentService.current,
        this.tuningService.tunings
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
}
```

The AJAX requests are sent but I never pass in the `subscribe` callback.

If I try to execute each request separatly it works fine :

```
 this.instrumentService.current.subscribe(instrument => {
     console.log(instrument);
     this.instrument = instrument;
 });

 this.tuningService.tunings.subscribe(tunings => {
     console.log(tunings);
     this.tunings = tunings;
 });
```

In the data services (`instrumentService` and `tuningService`), the `Observable` are declared like this (maybe the source of the bug, don't know) :

```
private _tunings: BehaviorSubject<Tuning[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

/**
 * Class constructor.
 *
 * @param {ApiService} apiService
 */
constructor (private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.getAll().subscribe(tunings => this._tunings.next(tunings));
}

public get tunings() {
    return this._tunings.asObservable();
}

public getAll(): Observable<Tuning[]> {
    return this.apiService.call(this.url);
}
```

The `apiService` is responsible of calling the built-in angular `http` service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i remember `forkJoin` currently has a bug, if one of the `Observable` returns `null` then the `forkJoin` subscription is never called. Can you try with `.zip` instead?

Comment: Yes that's it. One of my `BehaviorSubject` uses `null` as initial state. Works fine with `zip` method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the `combineLatest` rxjs operator turned out to be the one I was looking for.  It works with BehaviorSubjects the way you probably expected `forkJoin` to work:

> When any observable emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each.

(Documentation: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)